# A specific view cannot extend the layout file in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, layout, view

I am working on a charity website using Laravel 7, I have a main layout file which has been extended in two views, the `index` view and the `show` view, both views are in the same directory and for testing purpose, I have copied the code from `index` view and pasted it in `show` view but the `index` view shows the styling and everything correctly but when the `show` view is loaded, it does not have `css` styles and `js`, below are all the relevant files:

The `layout` view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>  
@include('partials.header')
@yield('styles') 
</head>
<body>
   @include('partials.nav')
   @yield('content')
   @include('partials.footer')  
<!-- loader -->
<div id="ftco-loader" class="show fullscreen"><svg class="circular" width="48px" height="48px"> 
<circle class="path-bg" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#eeeeee"/><circle 
class="path" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" 
stroke="#F96D00"/></svg></div>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/aos.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="js/google-map.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
@yield('scripts')

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `index` view that works correctly:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<div class="site-section fund-raisers bg-light">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-3 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
      <h2>All Fundraisers</h2>
      <p class="lead">These are the fundraisers that require your little help to give hope to the 
 ones in need.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">


    <!-- <div class="row"> -->

    <div class="col-md-12 block-11">
    <div class="nonloop-block-11 owl-carousel">

   @foreach($causes as $cause)


        <div class="card fundraise-item">

          <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset($cause->image) }}" alt="Image 
  placeholder"></a>

          <div class="card-body">

            <h3 class="card-title"><a href="{{ route('causes.show', $cause->id) }}">{{ $cause->title 
  }}</a></h3>

            <p class="card-text">{{ $cause->body }}</p>

            <span class="donation-time mb-3 d-block">Last donation 1w ago</span>

            <div class="progress custom-progress-success">
              <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%" aria- 
  valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>

            <span class="fund-raised d-block">$12,000 raised of $30,000</span>

          </div>

        </div>

    @endforeach



    </div>

 </div>

 <br />
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-cente"> {{ $causes->links() }} </div>

 </div>
 </div>

 @endsection
```

This is the `show` view which shows one item but does not work correctly:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<div class="site-section fund-raisers bg-light">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-3 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
      <h2>All Fundraisers</h2>
      <p class="lead">These are the fundraisers that require your little help to give hope to the 
 ones in need.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">


    <!-- <div class="row"> -->

    <div class="col-md-12 block-11">
    <div class="nonloop-block-11 owl-carousel">



        <div class="card fundraise-item">

          <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset($cause->image) }}" alt="Image 
  placeholder"></a>

          <div class="card-body">

            <h3 class="card-title"><a href="">{{ $cause->title }}</a></h3>

            <p class="card-text">{{ $cause->body }}</p>

            <span class="donation-time mb-3 d-block">Last donation 1w ago</span>

            <div class="progress custom-progress-success">
              <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%" aria- 
   valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>

            <span class="fund-raised d-block">$12,000 raised of $30,000</span>

          </div>

        </div>




    </div>

    </div>


  </div>
 </div>



 @endsection
```

This is the `controller` file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Cause as Cause;

class CausesController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $causes = Cause::take(15)->paginate(5);

    return view('causes.index', ['causes' => $causes]);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $cause = Cause::findOrFail($id)->first();

    return view('causes.show', ['cause' => $cause]);
}
```

Here is the `web.php` file for routes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;



Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.index');

Route::get('/causes', 'CausesController@index')->name('causes.index');
Route::get('/causes/{id}', 'CausesController@show')->name('causes.show');
```

Below image shows the path of both `index` and `show` views:
[image: path-to-index-and-show-views]

I tried my best for two days to find a solution for it but nothing helped, any assistance in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the route for Show View???

Comment: I think that is not your View issue. Seems like your code does not reach your show() function.

Comment: @AkshayKhale : I added the routes file, you can see it now.

Comment: @Ts8060 : If the code could not reach the show() method then the view would not be rendered , here the view is rendered but the css and js formatting is not there.

Comment: @AbdulRaheemGhani Sorry. I thought Show View is not rendering. use url() function to call js and css. url('js/aos.js') like this. Or easiest but not recommended way is add / in front of your js and css <script src='/js/aos.js'></script> like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not in your view code or your logic. Everything is correct. Only the issue is the way you are loading your static resources i.e. the CSS and JS file.

I think you must have placed your CSS and JS files in the public folder so when you access the index route JS URL becomes

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but when you are trying to search those CSS and JS files in

```
<script src="causes/{id}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What you can try doing is:

```
<script src="{{ url('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

That's just to fix your issue, ideally, you should be keeping those files in Resource folder and should be using Laravel Mix to compile those files and autoload those.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix

Comment: Great that I could help you but as I suggested, try using Laravel Mix to manage the Static Assets. @AbdulRaheemGhani

Comment: Yeah, I started using it for static assets.